# wpf outlook-like interface

Tags: wpf, user-interface, interface, outlook

Can anyone point me to a tutorial on how to create an outlook like interface in WPF?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2007/06/13/wpf-hands-on-lab-build-an-outlook-2007-ui-clone.aspx). Note that you could have easily found this yourself with the aid of Google.