# HTML style left menu bar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to create a HTML style left menu bar in WPF but have no clue on which controls to customize or use (basically I want to create similar feature like some web page dashboard left hand side menu bar style).

Can someone point me on some resources?

I tried to check on this link [wpf outlook-like interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594506/wpf-outlook-like-interface) but the Microsoft download link is invalid and cannot get my hand on this tutorial anymore.

What I would like to achieve is something like a stack panel + expander in vertical orientation.

[image: Example of HTML Left Menu bar]

So far, what I have tried is: I tried to customize expander with buttons in blend with my little knowledge (but the button is not align to left side of the expander when I move my mouse over as you can see from above pic.) + rounded buttons all in stack panel.

From my what I have tried so far, 
1. there are gaps in between on each stack panel objects. 
2. Button in Expander is not fully strecth horizontally.

Am I using the correct control or ways?

**[Edit]**
By using Expander + Buttons + Stackpanel, I manage to achieve what I wanted. 
Due to padding and margin issue, it cause the gap. 
Here is what I want to do and achieved. (Thanks @mahlatse for pointing out the root cause).
[image]

Comment: Maybe start looking at your margins, padding and positioning of the various elements. also look at Templates, they work wonders.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817624/wpf-how-to-create-a-lateral-menu-like-this-modern-ui

Comment: @Ferus7, thanks for the link, it will definitely help me in what I am doing right now.

Comment: @mahlatse, thanks for the guide, I will dig further into each margin, padding and alignment.

Comment: Finally, figure out the issues (just like what @mahlatse point out), by using Blend, go into each controls and setting padding and margin to zero (accordingly). Since I cannot answer to my questions, for those who interested in above style, you can feel free to contact me. What I want to achieve may look similar to the duplicate question link but design is different. I customize Expander to right arrow. not limit to one at a time expander opening.